# YUICompressor.NET Method not found ICompressor.get_ContentType() error

Tags: asp.net, minify, yui-compressor

I'm trying to use YUICompressor.NET in my project. It is an asp.net mvc web project, framework 4.5.1.

I'm getting this error :

```
Method not found: 'System.String Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.ICompressor.get_ContentType()'.
```

at :

```
Line 6:      <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
Line 7:      @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
Line 8:      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
Line 9:
```

Anybody has an idea ?

I followed the instructions in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSHGSbViMm8 ) and changed the contents of RegisterBundles method as follows :

```
var javascriptConfig = new JavaScriptCompressorConfig();
var javascriptTransform = new YuiCompressorTransform(javascriptConfig);

bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery", javascriptTransform).Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jqueryval", javascriptTransform).Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

// Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
// ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/modernizr", javascriptTransform).Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", javascriptTransform).Include(
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Here is the stack trace :
    [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.ICompressor.get_ContentType()'.]
               Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Web.Optimization.YuiCompressorTransform.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response) +0
       System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +273
       System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +141
       System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +45
       System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) +166
       System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.EliminateDuplicatesAndResolveUrls(IEnumerable`1 refs) +296
       System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) +733
       System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +35
       System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +105
       System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(String[] paths) +21
       ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Entegral\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml:8
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
       System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
       System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90

Answer (score 4):

The `YUICompressor.NET.Web.Optimization` nuget package in version 2.7.0 has an incorrect dependency. It requires `YUICompressor.NET` in version 2.0.0 or higher. But version 2.7.0 is required.

An upgrade of `YUICompressor.NET` to version 2.7.0 should fix it.

Comment: thanks a low. i finally gave up YUICompressor and started using squishit:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/SquishIt. It is much more painless !